# Is it a good practice to have a separate definition for controller when using directive

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. And I have been experimenting with "directives". When using directives i found the following 2 ways to use controller with a directive.

Approach 1

```
angular.module('folderSettingApp')
    .directive('templateRenderer', function () {
        return {
            // other options
            , controller: 'GridController'
        };
    });
```

Approach 2

```
angular.module('folderSettingApp')
    .directive('templateRenderer', function () {
        return {
            // other options
            , controller: function ($scope, $attrs) {
               // add some functions here
            }
        };
    });
```

I am not sure what approach to use when, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so general to use which one, it's based on your use,

For example, if you want to use a directive multiple time in your app, it's better you don't define any controller in your directive, like this:

```
.directive('exampleDirective', function (){
    return {
        restrict: "A", // OR E OR AE OR C
        template: "<div>YOUR TEMPLATE HERE</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            // what ever function you want whould be here:
        }
    }
});
```

But generally, for the sake of angular's modularity, it's not a good idea to define a controller in directives.

Because the aim of directive is to use it in multiple controller and multiple views.

So defining a controller in a directive, just makes that directive less modular with restricted use.

Answer (score 0):

One argument for the separate controller is for ease of testing. It's not hard at all to write tests which instantiate and allow you to test individual code on a separate controller.